# How to fetch subcategories under a category Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How to display subcategories under a category or match "category_id" of "category table" and "subcategory table" and display using blade?? I attached the image of my two tables- category table and subcategory table.
I want to display subcategories under a category. U can suggest only the form of foreach loop as well.[image: subcategory table]

[image: category table]

Though I tried several stuffs. this is my last try:

```
@if(isset($subcategories))
@foreach( $subcategories as $subcat )   
    <tr>
       <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class='checkbox' value="{{ $subcat->category_id }}">
       </td>
       <td>
            {{ $subcat->category_id }}
      </td>
      <td>
            @foreach( $subcat->category_id as $subcategory )
                {{ $subcategory->subcategory }}
            @endforeach
      </td>

     </tr>  
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Because at the moment, it looks like you’re asking someone to write code for you, for a problem that could be answered by reading through [Laravel’s documentation on Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) for a few minutes.

Comment: you should practice the examples before you dive into real life problems

Comment: I updated with my stuffs .. though i did several stuffs. sorry for bothering u. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer .. I added the stuff in my blade.

```
@foreach(Subcategory::where('category_id','=',$cat->id)->get() as $subcat)
    <input type="checkbox" class='checkbox' value="{{ $cat->id }}">
    {{ $subcat->subcategory }}
    <br>
@endforeach
```